# Are the attribute pairs supported by calling SQLConfigDataSource() with ODBCJT32.DLL and ACEODBC.DLL documented anywhere?

Tags: odbc, jet

A few years ago I was able to use PInvoke to create Microsoft Access databases without access installed via the API call [SQLConfigDataSource()](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/odbccp32/SQLConfigDataSource.html). The code is [here](https://github.com/zippy1981/plane-disaster/blob/master/PlaneDisaster.Dba/JetSqlUtil.cs).

I've ported that PInvoke call to work on [Windows 7 and powershell 2.0](https://gist.github.com/1166670).

I know that `ODBCJT32.DLL` supports at least the following:

- COMPACT_DB
- CREATE_DBV2
- CREATE_DBV3
- CREATE_DBV4
- CREATE_DB
- REPAIR_DB

And I know that `ACEODBC.DLL` suppports at least CREATE_DB and will experiment with the others. However, I've never actually found a MSDN document with an authoritative list of what attribute pairs are supported. Does one exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calls for ODBCJT32.DLL are documented in the MSDN page entitled [SQLConfigDataSource (Access Driver)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However, it is incomplete. It incorrectly calls CREATE_DBV2 CREATE_V2DB and does not list CREATE_DBV3 or CREATE_DBV4. This is all pointed out in [KB126606](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126606).